# How to align overlapping images, centered with synchronous resizing?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this composite image from a combination of images:
[image]

I have tried div tags with relative positioning and z-indices, but to no avail. Complicating things is that I need the composite image to be able to resize automatically, with all sub-images resizing appropriately yet staying aligned.

The solution needs to be html and css only. No javascript. And not nested svgs (I need this to also be appropriate for bitmap images).

Here is my feeble attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/kb0sgd7h/1/

```html
<div style="width:100%;position:relative; z-index:0; text-align: center; display: block;">
    <div style="positive:absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left:10; top:0; z-index:1;text-align: center;display: block;">
         <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnjustin/svgtest/master/circles.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div style="positive:absolute; width: 80%; height: 80%; left:10; top:0; z-index:0;text-align: center;display: block;">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnjustin/svgtest/master/justin.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div style="positive:absolute; width: 80px; height: 80px; left:0; top:0; margin-top:-100px; z-index:2;text-align: center;display: block;">
        <img  src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnjustin/svgtest/master/stay-home.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div style="positive:absolute; width: 80px; height: 80px; left:0; top:-100; margin-top:-100px; z-index:2;text-align: center;display: block;">
       <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnjustin/svgtest/master/employee.svg"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can use is to have multiple `background-image`s (each with their own `background-position` and `background-size`).  I've included a demo with a stock image and two blue circles composited on top.  Everything should scale together as you resize the page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 10% left 10%, bottom 10% right 10%, center;
  background-size: 20%, 20%, cover;
  background-image: url('https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/shape/29779-8-circle-file.png'), url('https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/shape/29779-8-circle-file.png'), url('https://www.b3multimedia.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/free-stock-images-websites.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But, at least with percentages for positioning, it doesn’t scale properly on an individual element basis. Is there a way to absolutely position without percentages yet still center everything upon resize

Comment: @user9375050, I think the issue you were seeing is that the `background-size` percentages were only reacting to changes to the width.  In the code above, I have replaced `height` with `padding-top` to preserve the aspect ratio (1:1 in the demo).  Does that suit your purposes?